# Do I need to release my instance object before assigning another object to it's reference?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an NSMutableArray of objects (in my case some systems). I'm requesting new data for the systems by reading XML's and from them I'm creating some new systems. In some cases I want to update the systems in my NSMutableArray, sometimes not..
Therefore, when I want an update I say

`system = [updatedSystem copy];`

(My system model has implemented `- (id)copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone`)

My question is, do I need to release my old system object prior to `system = [updatedSystem copy];`?

I.e.
`[system release];`

`system = [updatedSystem copy];`

Comment: Why not use a property? They encapsulate memory management code and reduce boilerplate.

Comment: Since my system model has a lot of different properties I need to do a deep copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if copied it, you have to `release`, cause the copied object isn't released before being returned from the copy function.

Comment: So it's not handled automatically when using = [object copy]?

Comment: Yes, you **have** to release the copied object

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that you take ownership of releasing whenever you use init, new, or copy.  If you copied it, you're responsible to release it.

See the following article from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html